# Guidelines for Facebook usage (how many invites can I sent)?

Tags: facebook

I'm developing a Chrome extension partially similar to another already approved by Facebook: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/invite-post-likers-to-lik/dfhnkeijhilolcebpchcdiclpejojodb?hl=en

My extension allows to invite people, that reacted to a publication, to like the page of that publication. So people who liked a post, receive an invite saying something like "You liked this post, do you wanna receive updates from this page".

I noticed that by using the extension, sometimes I would get a message stating that "You’re Temporarily Blocked. It looks like you were misusing this feature by going too fast. You’ve been blocked from using it." To avoid that I added a pause between each click of 1 second. Also, I added a pause between loading new reactions of 2.5 seconds. Even so, on rare occasions I still get blocked.

I looked for headers about usage limit, similar to the ones for the Graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/overview/rate-limiting/) but it seems that they are not sent in responses to the FB site itself.

I imagine, in the future, Facebook will either block these invites at all, or let people just invite everyone. As it sits is just a "difficult" feature.

For the time being are there any guidelines I can follow?

Thanks,

Comment: _“already approved by Facebook”_ - where does it say that …?

Comment: “Going too fast” here means that the account this is happening under, has sent out too many invites within a given time frame, or that not enough of the already sent invites were met with a positive response by then - in which case, Facebook temporarily blocks the account from sending any further ones. But this is considering a longer time frame, pausing for a couple of seconds between sending those requests is not going to help.

Comment: It says in the last paragraph (in the link) that fb approved it in May 2017.

I do notice differences with and without the delay. If there is no delay I get banned really quick (after 10 consecutives invites or 5 requests for more reactions; more or less). So it seems there are some short time frames as well.

But the question, where is this documented, so I can respect FB times.

Comment: Sure, they are likely looking at more than one factor. But stuff like this does not get officially documented anywhere, that would only help spammers.